# launch csh script from python in a separate thread

Tags: python, subprocess, csh

I am trying to run a csh script from python in a separate thread i.e. I don't want to wait for the script to complete.

I am trying to do this:

```
subprocess.call(['my_script.csh -w switch'])
print 'Job spawned..'
```

The problem is that the message is being print after the csh script is completed. Is there a way a just spawn the csh job and continue python

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects):

```
from subprocess import Popen
process = Popen(['sleep', '5'])
print 'job spawned'
process.wait()
print 'job complete'
```

To clear up your terminology, a "thread" is a line of execution within a single program, whereas a "process" is a running program (which may have multiple threads).  When you start a program, it's almost always a separate process, which means it's running independently and asynchronously (not on the same thread).  The issue here is that `subprocess.call` is written for the most common use cases, where you probably want to wait for the called process to finish before continuing.  `subprocess.Popen` is a class that gives you a lot more power.  It doesn't wait for the process to finish unless you tell it to, using the `wait()` method.

Comment: Also, you don't want to start threads and then start processes -- that way lies deadlocks.